# Can Not Install Any ARM Version of Python with Pyenv

Tags: xcode, openssl, pyenv

I'm getting the "common" missing readline and missing openssl errors, but not finding any solution after 5 days of working on this.

I loaded an ARM version of Homebrew and I’m calling pyenv with: arch -arm64 pyenv.

I went through the pyenv "Common Build Problems" wiki, in addition to reinstalling Xcode, Homebrew, pyenv, and dozens of compiler and linker flag settings. I am still getting these common two errors but can't seem to solve them:

```
    WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
    ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

Is the "Python ssl extension" separate from the openssl that I'm referring to in my install command? I'm confused.
I'm also confused about why setting the flags in my install command gives me different results when those flags are already set in my .zshrc file.

Install command:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1" \
pyenv install -v 3.11.7
```

The initial response from this is:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
/var/folders/xk/vp0pdf492tl589vtnykls31r0000gn/T/python-build.20240103094955.95458 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/lib
Downloading Python-3.11.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.7/Python-3.11.7.tar.xz
/var/folders/xk/vp0pdf492tl589vtnykls31r0000gn/T/python-build.20240103094955.95458/Python-3.11.7 /var/folders/xk/vp0pdf492tl589vtnykls31r0000gn/T/python-build.20240103094955.95458 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/lib
Installing Python-3.11.7...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
So, it obviously sees those libraries.
```

My environment looks like this:

```
% env
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/zsh
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/xk/vp0pdf492tl589vtnykls31r0000gn/T/
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=452
TERM_SESSION_ID=C6EB3B82-E4BE-4F5C-A738-A6B50375CFC6
USER=russ
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.gJihUjYw6p/Listeners
PATH=/Users/russ/.pyenv/bin:/opt/homebrew:/opt/homebrew/opt/readine:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1:/Users/russ/.pyenv/bin:/opt/homebrew:/opt/homebrew/opt/readine:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1:/Users/russ/.pyenv/bin:/opt/homebrew:/opt/homebrew/opt/readine:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
LaunchInstanceID=1FF9E430-720A-4401-A85E-45CC8250E050
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
PWD=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/lib
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/russ
LOGNAME=russ
SECURITYSESSIONID=18790
OLDPWD=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/lib
HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew
MANPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/man::
INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info:
PYENV_ROOT=/Users/russ/.pyenv
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

And my .zshrc file looks like this:

```
setopt no_nomatch

echo "Now reading .zshrc..."

alias arm="env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login"
alias intel="env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login"

alias brew86="arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew"
alias brew="arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew"

alias pyenv86="arch -x86_64 pyenv"
alias pyenv="arch -arm64 pyenv"

#For pyenv:
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm grasping at straws at this point. I think I've seen every post written about pyenv install problems but I am open to retrying

If anyone has an ARM version of pyenv working at this point, I would love to know because I'm about ready to throw the towel in on pyenv at this point and assume that it simply doesn’t work natively on ARM (rather than through Rosetta). My x86 version on the same Mac M1 Max laptop works flawlessly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will post the core problem here in case others are facing the same issue (and it appears that many are). Homebrew + Pyenv is causing a failure. Is it Homebrew or Pyenv or the interaction between the two? I don't know for sure, but suspect that it's Homebrew.

I slowly realized that "upside-down world" was occurring where each library that I added to Homebrew was causing *that library* to go missing in the python install process-- readline, openssl, ncurses.... I force-removed any library that was throwing an error during install because it was "missing" from Homebrew. These were then automatically downloaded during the install, allowing for a successful install of the python version.

Will you now get an ARM-native python install? No, because the python wheels are not ARM-native yet, but at least the tools are ready for them when they start arriving.